# Вход в беседу с помощью VK API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как с помощью *python* и запуском кода сделать так, чтобы указанный токен пользователя в коде заходил в указанную беседу? То есть, запуская код, страница заходит в беседу, которую я указал.

Comment: В беседу нужно вступить по ссылке или из которой вышел пользователь?

Comment: нужно просто чтобы я указывал ссылку на беседу и токен страницы которую я указал входил в беседу по указанной ссылке

Comment: нужно вступить по ссылке

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы подключиться к беседе по ссылке нужно воспользоваться методом [messages.joinChatByInviteLink](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.joinChatByInviteLink). Если планируете только добавлять пользователя, то можно воспользоваться библиотекой [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```py
import requests

token = input("Токен пользователя: ")
link = input("Ссылка на беседу: ")
requests.post(
    'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.joinChatByInviteLink',
    data={
        "access_token": token,
        "link": link,
        "v": "5.131",
    }
)
```